# "The getter 'documents' isn't defined for the type 'Object'"

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to CS. I'm working on a messaging system for an app, but I get this error: The getter 'documents' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. I've seen other stackoverflow solutions but none of them have worked, maybe I'm not using them correctly. Here is my code:

```
Widget searchUsersList() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: usersStream,
      builder: ((context, snapshot) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.documents.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data!.documents[index];
            return Image.network(ds["imageUrl"]);
          },
        );
      }),
    );
  }
```

The error occurs in both places where I have !.documents written. Any idea what how to fix? The base code is mostly taken from a YouTube tutorial that is a couple of years old, so I'm not surprised that it no longer works, but I'm out of ideas. Thanks

I tried using other solutions such as putting "BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot" in the itemBuilder, but that didn't work. I've also tried using StreamBuilder but that just added an error under usersStream.

Answer (score 0):

this code do not throw any errors :

```
 return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
                stream:
                    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("c").snapshots(),
                builder: ((BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>
                        snapshot) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                      return Image.network(ds["imageUrl"]);
                    },
                  );
                }),
              );
```

read the migration changes of the firestore:
[Migration to cloud_firestore 2.0.0](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/2.0.0_migration)